# How to send bulk emails using PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I am developing my first project in PHP and am new. Yesterday I needed to create a feature that sends email notification of new post to all site members. I created a feature and I don't know how good it is.

After creating a post, I selected all the site members in sql -

include "db.php";

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$runQuery = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

This gives me all the site members. Then I looped through the array and grabbed email id of each member like this -

```
while($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery) {
    $email = $users['email'];
}
```

This way I have each member's email id. Now in the loop, I can use mail() function to send email to each site member.

For better code writing, I wrote sending email code in another document and linked it using 'include()' function. Like this -

```
while($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery) {
     $email = $users['email'];

include "send_email.php";
}
```

Where send email file has $header, $email_subject, $email_body and the $email that is coming from this loop. So each time the loop runs, it has new email id and the mail is sent to that email id.

This code worked on my localhost, even in production(hostgator hosting) till there are few site members. But, when I tested it on my live site(has more than 70 members), the page stucked for at least 10 seconds and returned an error 'Page is not working'.

So what is actually happening here? Why is it not able to send emails to more users?

Comment: is php mail setup on the live server?  without seeing the server logs its very difficult to debug.  A point though, including a file like that is certainly not 'better code writing'.   Better would be to construct a mailer class and use that.

Comment: Yes php mail is setup. I told you it successfully sent emails to some members but when I looped through 70+ users, it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you are including "send_mail.php" file every step and this means a lot of memory and CPU usage. So why don't you do it like this :

send_mail.php file :

```
function sendMail($email){
   //your mail stuff..
}
```

Your while loop :

```
include "send_mail.php";
while($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runQuery)){
    $email = $users['email'];
    sendMail($email);
}
```

Also PHP Scripts have time limitation for executing code. If you want to bypass it you have to write this code to top of your file(that has while loop) :

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. And in send_mail.php I have $header, $email_subject, $email_body, $email and mail() finally that send email. So will putting the same code as function do the work for me.

And I will try set_time_limit(0). One more question, how many minutes or seconds should I enter.

Comment: Okay. I'm trying it out. And please tell me if that is good to increase time limitation to 1 minute?

Comment: Thank you Erol Keskin it seems to work. This time the server did not throw any error. But I think the email was not sent to all members. I just talked to one of the site member and he told me that he has received no email. So perhaps there is still something wrong.